# Why is the input pin to my multiplexer considered a capacitive load?

Tags: capacitance, signal-integrity, input-impedance

I am currently using [CD74HC4067 multiplexer](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4067.pdf) in my design.

I had trouble with my input signal and therefore conducted an experiment by measuring the input resistance of my multiplexer as the frequency increases. I noticed that as the frequency is increased from 1 KHz to a final value of 8 MHz that the input resistance decreases with the increase in frequency. I am guessing that therefore this is a capacitive load because impedance = 1/(jwc) where w is the frequency. But why would the input pin be capacitive as opposed to purely resistive for an input pin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mux is CMOS; MOS gates have capacitance [by design]... and a lot of other parasitic ones. But even with BJTs you have parasitic capacitance.

Here's what CMOS analog switch (as would be used in a multiplexer) typically looks like

[image]

Image from [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=iXpb5xXTEEsC).

Every MOSFET has [parasitic] capacitance between [everything and everything basically](http://www.doe.carleton.ca/~len/477W2003/LectureNotes/January_13_2003_2up.pdf), so there is a capacitive path from an analog input to... well anything. I'm not actually sure relative to what you've measured it (output, ground?), but doesn't really matter, because some capacitance exists relative to any of these.

[image]

In particular all MOSFETs in a CMOS will have capacitance via the bulk substrate:

[image]

Someone more versed than me in IC design can probably guess how you've measured it based on the result you've got.

Comment: That's for the control inputs. The analog inputs connect to the sources and drains of a transmission gate.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: thanks, I think I fixed that.